# How do I make IntelliJ respect Maven Kotlin plugin output directory?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-14

I am writing Kotlin and compiling to JavaScript.  I also have some HTML/CSS resources.  I have a Maven project setup that copies my HTML resources to the build directory and the `kotlin-maven-plugin` has its `outputFile` location set to be a subdirectory of the output directory (`${project.build.directory}/js/${project.artifactId}.js`).  When building with maven this behaves exactly as expected and my output directory contains my compiled JavaScript file in the `js` folder and my HTML/CSS files in the appropriate places.

When I import the project into IntelliJ however, it doesn't respect the `outputFile` location set in the pom.xml and instead drops my generated JavScript file into `target\classes`.

I can fix this after import by going into `Project Structure > Project Settings > Modules > Paths > Compiler Output > Output Path` and changing it to `target\js` but I would like to be able to setup the pom.xml in such a way that this step is unnecessary.

On a related note, why does setting the output path not result in my HTML/CSS files getting dropped into `target\js`?  It would seem that the output path isn't being respected by the `resource` copy.

Edit: Here is the pom.xml excert:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>js</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>js</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/js/${project.artifactId}.js</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you down-vote, please indicate what the problem with the question is so I can improve it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps you might add the relevant `kotlin-maven-plugin` snippet from your POM.

Comment: Looks like bug, please create an issue about it in [the tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KT) with simple example. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, there is such an issue already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6749

Comment: The final comments from the issue linked by @AndreyBreslav are in the answer below, it is resolved or there is an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks resolved, or that there is another option.  From the issue mentioned in comments to the question (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6749):

> When you import maven project in IntelliJ, if "Use Maven output directories" is selected, then the output path will be set to ${project.build.outputDirectory}, which is by default is ${project.build.directory}/classes (see http://maven.apache.org/pom.html for details).
>
> The following should work:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/js</outputDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

> For now the default value for parameter `outputFile` (`kotlin-maven-plugin, goal:js`) is `${project.build.directory}/js/${project.artifactId}.js`.
>
> It seems it should be changed to  `${project.build.outputDirectory}/${project.artifactId}.js` (commit https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/0b35989367291e88568567a293ed7224f809d605)